Humanoid monster who rips out a throat
Please help me identify this horror movie:
I saw this one with my uncles in the early 90's. They watched Shocker (1989) a few days earlier so I'm guessing that the movie I'm seeking is from around the same time period. It has been a really long time so I only remember a few vague things about it. I apologize about that.

There was a scientist who had a small boy with him a lot, probably his son.
There was a scene in which the scientist was working late and the boy saw that blood was filling up the water bottle on top of a water dispenser.
There was a very violent scene in which the humanoid monster ripped out someone (probably the scientist)'s throat while both were standing. There was a lot of blood and I think the boy witnessed it.
I want to say that the monster was green and the scientist was a white man with facial hair.

It was Western film with English most likely being the spoken language.
I would really love to see that movie again. I appreciate your help.

Could be horror film The House By The Cemetery from 1981 (which is Italian, but maybe it was dubbed) about a (bearded) researcher who moves with his wife and little son to a house by a, well, cemetery; There is a scene where his throat is ripped out by a corpse with a green-tinted face in front of his son. Can't place the water scene, but there IS some sort of water dispenser in the trailer [WARNING: NSFW] around 0:50:




Can't believe you found it! Thank you so much.
